# Return 1 row per unique id instead of multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql query which returns a list of students which are enrolled in a conference, and their preferences for each session. When pulling the data from my database, each user session selection is showing in its own row as shown below:

```
**userid      question              answer**
1        S1 choose: a1, b1, c1      a1
1        S2 choose: a2, b2, c2      b2
1        S3 choose: a3, b3, c3      b3
2        S1 choose: a1, b1, c1      b1
2        S2 choose: a2, b2, c2      c2
2        S3 choose: a3, b3, c3      a3
3        S1 choose: a1, b1, c1      a1
3        S2 choose: a2, b2, c2      b2
3        S3 choose: a3, b3, c3      b3
```

I would like to make each session a colum, so that each userid with the questions and answers is shown in one row.  Like so:

```
user1 question1 answer1 question2 answer2 question3 answer3
user2 question1 answer1 question2 answer2 question3 answer3
user3 question1 answer1 question2 answer2 question3 answer3
```

I'm limited to my SQL query knowledge so I would greatly appreciate your help....how can I reach the above results?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which `RDBMS` are you using?  And do you know the number of questions or is it dynamic?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008. The number of questions varies per conference.

Comment: Also, it is often easier to do this with presentation code such as .net, coldfusion, etc.  Is that available to you?

Comment: You should perform the output formating with a regular programing language, iterating over the results. You are trying to combine 2 columns of 3 rows into 6 columns with 1 row... that's no logical conversion for a Query language.

Comment: @DanBracuk I don't have presentation code available for now.

Comment: @user3356789 -- What you're trying to do is `pivot` your results and since you don't know the number of columns, you'll need to use `dynamic sql` to do this.  Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: @sgeddes what if I knew the number of columns, how can I do this?

Comment: If you know the number of columns is also a `PIVOT` but you can skip the dynamic part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your comment, assuming you know the number of potential questions, one option is to use `max` with `case`:

```
select userid,
       max(case when questionid = 1 then question end) question1,
       max(case when questionid = 1 then answer end) answer1,
       max(case when questionid = 2 then question end) question2,
       max(case when questionid = 2 then answer end) answer2,
       ...
from yourtable
group by userid
```

This assumes you have a `questionid` available.  If not, you could use the `question` field or create a `ROW_NUMBER` and it would work the same way:

```
select userid,
       max(case when rn = 1 then question end) question1,
       max(case when rn = 1 then answer end) answer1,
       max(case when rn = 2 then question end) question2,
       max(case when rn = 2 then answer end) answer2,
       ...
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by userid order by question) rn
    from yourtable
) t
group by userid
```

---

Edit, if you need a dynamic solution for this, since you are trying to `pivot` multiple columns, you first need to unpivot your results.  One option for doing this is to use `CROSS APPLY`.  Then you can `PIVOT` the results back:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME('Question:' + question) +',' + QUOTENAME('Answer:' + question) 
                    from  yourtable
                    group by question
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'select userid, ' + @cols + '
from
(
  select userid,
    col+question new_col,
    value
  from yourtable
  cross apply
  (
    VALUES
        (question, ''Question:''),
        (answer, ''Answer:'')
   ) x (value, col)
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for new_col in (' + @cols + ')
) piv '

execute(@query)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6391/1)

Comment: Thakns @sgeddes. For now I'm creating them non-dynamically, but soon would have to make it dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic SQL.  Select a distinct list of sessions into a temp table that you've created with an identity column.

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(1000), @Count int, @Counter int
CREATE TABLE #report (userid int)
CREATE TABLE #questions (MyIdx int IDENTITY(1,1), question varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #report (UserID) SELECT DISTINCT userid from mytable
INSERT INTO #questions (question) SELECT DISTINCT question FROM mytable ORDER BY question

SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM #questions, @Counter = 0

WHILE @Counter < @Count
BEGIN
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1

    SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE #report ADD Q' + CONVERT(varchar, @Counter) + ' varchar(50)'

    EXEC (@SQL)

    SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE #report ADD A' + CONVERT(varchar, @Counter) + ' varchar(50)'

    EXEC (@SQL)

    SET @SQL = 'UPDATE #report SET Q' + CONVERT(varchar, @Counter) + ' = b.question FROM #report a INNER JOIN mytable b ON a.userid = b.userid INNER JOIN #questions c ON b.question = c.question WHERE c.MyIdx = ' + CONVERT(varchar, @Counter)

    EXEC (@SQL)

    SET @SQL = 'UPDATE #report SET A' + CONVERT(varchar, @Counter) + ' = b.answer FROM #report a INNER JOIN mytable b ON a.userid = b.userid AND a.question = b.Q' + CONVERT(varchar, @Counter)

    EXEC (@SQL)
END

SELECT * FROM #report ORDER BY userid

DROP TABLE #report

DROP TABLE #questions
```

That is, if you have an unknown number of sessions.  Otherwise, go with the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the example in the question is similar to your data a possibility is to split and union

```
SELECT userid
     , q1 = max(q1), a1 = max(a1)
     , q2 = max(q2), a2 = max(a2)
     , q3 = max(q3), a3 = max(a3)
FROM   (SELECT userid
             , q1 = question, a1 = answer
             , q2 = NULL, a2 = NULL
             , q3 = NULL, a3 = NULL
        FROM   table1
        WHERE  left(question, 2) = 'S1'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT userid
             , q1 = NULL, a1 = NULL
             , q2 = question, a2 = answer
             , q3 = NULL, a3 = NULL
        FROM   table1
        WHERE  left(question, 2) = 'S2'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT userid
             , q1 = NULL, a1 = NULL
             , q2 = NULL, a2 = NULL
             , q3 = question, a3 = answer
        FROM   table1
        WHERE  left(question, 2) = 'S3') d
GROUP BY userid
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49111/1)</kbd>

Each question code is used to split the data, while the other attribute a placed in the wanted columns. Every data split have `userid` so it can be used as anchor for grouping the other values to reduce the mapping to one line per `userid`.